# Checking Time Played - Sea of Thieves

Tags: pc, sea-of-thieves

I've searched the internet for months and haven't been able to find any way to view my Total Hours invested into the game.  I'm aware there is a way on XBox but I play on PC so that doesn't concern me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Seaofthieves/comments/8cm4yv/rare_please_let_me_see_the_amount_of_hours_ive/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Seaofthieves/comments/89p4eu/no_way_to_see_time_played/) Reddit thread, and the [Sea of Thieves forum](https://www.seaofthieves.com/forum/topic/45766/total-time-played), **total playing time just isn't available for Sea of Thieves**.

Most users suggest extrapolating the time spent playing from the Distance Sailed, or the amount of cargo you have delivered.

Answer (score -1):

There is one way, but I'm not sure if it's accurate. Open taskmanager then go to App History and look up Sea of Thieves, should tell you for how long it's been up and running

Comment: It probably wouldn't be accurate. App history measures CPU time, not time running. This can also be cleaned up and you'd lose your "total" time.